# SQL Select Query Across 3 Tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

Looking to print out a table, first column seatnumber as it is, second column the users username.

Full Image Diagram here:  http://iforce.co.nz/i/m0rvairk.hb4.png

Had a mate have a go, got this far:

```
    SELECT q802d_vikevents_orderseats.seatnum, q802d_users.username
      FROM q802d_vikevents_orderseats, q802d_vikevents_users
INNER JOIN q80d_users ON q802d_vikevent_users.ujid=q802d_users.ujid
INNER JOIN
```

Comment: what's the last table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@UrGuardian4ngel response looks correct (once name of third table is confirmed). Another way to write this would be as follows:

```
select s.seatnum,
       t.username
  from q802d_vikevents_orderseats s,
       q802d_vikevent_users vu,
       mystery_third_table t
 where vu.id = s.uid
   and t.id = vu.ujid;
```

Comment: Third table is 'q802d_users'. But it doesnt appear to be working, see http://aucklan.com/index.php/event Error message. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error says that one of the table (q802d_vikevent_users) does not exist. What RDBMS are you using? Are you able to provide the schema e.g. in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! I just realise that the fourth line of code wasnt quite correct, 'q802d_vikevent_users' --> 'q802d_vikevents_users'.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this table names. Your screen shot isn't that clear at the end (missing table name). But might work as is.

```
SELECT
    s.seatnum,
    u.username
FROM q802d_vikevents_orderseats s
INNER JOIN q802d_vikevent_users vu
        ON vu.id = s.uid
INNER JOIN q802d_users u
        ON u.id = ujid;
```